# Installing TeamViewer 13 on Debian requires many dependencies

Tags: installation, debian-based, teamviewer

I'm trying to install TeamViewer by going to their website and downloading the latest version.  However, when I open a terminal, navigate to the folder, and enter

```
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_13.0.6634_amd64.deb
```

I get a message that certain dependencies are missing, including `qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin`.  I then installed that, re-ran the install, and there are many other missing dependencies, so I try to just run

```
sudo apt install qtdeclarative5-*
```

and this tells me that several dependencies from `qml` are needed, so I run

```
sudo apt install qml-module-*
```

and this again tells me I first need *other* missing dependencies, and at this point I feel like I am in an endless maze.  Is there any efficient way of getting the dependencies that I need?  Or am I supposed to be doing something completely different to install TeamViewer?  I'm running Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon.

Comment: I actually found an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/136810/how-to-install-teamviewer

Comment: using qtdeclarative5-* not really the best practice. It may be not a endless maze. Try installing all the missing dependencies

Answer (score -2):

Why not use VNC?

This is a question more relevant for ServerFault, Stack Overflow's sister site for IT.

Comment: Is this still more relevant even if I'm using a laptop and not a server?  Something tells me at a place like that they'll assume I know the first thing about servers, which I don't.

Comment: Still relevant.  You are already working with Debian so most answers shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Because my  mac is behind firewall, how you will achieve this vnc? You install TeamViewer and it just works, no DynDNS, or other dances with dun drum...